# How will the European Parliament look after brexit?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, european-parliament

So 751 different members of the European Parliament was elected. However, some extra members were also elected for some countries for which the extra members first join the parliament the day (when/if) The United Kingdom leaves the European Union.

I can easily find a how the parliament just elected looks with the numbers of MEPs representing the political groups (EPP, S&D and so on). However my question is how many members will each european political group have post brexit?

**EDIT**: Accoording to the European Union the extra seats are shared as follows:
http://www.europarl.europa.eu/resources/library/media/20180123RES92302/20180123RES92302.pdf

Comment: Do you actually have access to a firm statement that those members would be seated if Brexit were post 1st July? My understanding was that the 705 seat distribution was conditional on Brexit occurring before the new session starts.

Comment: Of my knowledge these seats are distributed if ever the United Kingdom are to leave the EU and does not depend on any deadline. For example Denmark elected a extra seat which first join the parliament after brexit (see: https://www.dr.dk/nyheder/politik/resultater/ep-valg (in danish))

Comment: While I can't find anything to back this up, I would suspect that the new seat appropriations won't take effect until the first election after Brexit.  Main reason being that some countries' electoral systems (Ireland in particular given their use of STV) don't really work in this kind of situation.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I just found the text of the European Council decision that says that the other member states get their seats at the moment the UK withdraws from the EU.  See Article 3(2): https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32018D0937&from=EN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is based on a mix of official information and my own calculations:

- EPP: 184 (+5)
- S&D: 148 (-5)
- RE (formerly ALDE): 95 (-11)
- GRN/EFA: 66 (-8)
- GUE/NGL: 37 (-1)
- ECR: 64 (±0)
- EFDD: 25 (-29)
- ENF: 61 (+3)
- NI: 25 (±0)

Change by member state:

```
+-------+---+---+---+-----+---+---+----+---+--+
|Country|EPP|S&D|RE |G/EFA|GUE|ECR|EFDD|ENF|NI|
+-------+---+---+---+-----+---+---+----+---+--+
|UK     |   |-10|-17|  -11| -1| -4| -29|   |-1|
|FR     |   | +1| +2|   +1|   |   |    | +1|  |
|IT     | +1|   |   |     |   | +1|    | +1|  |
|ES     | +1| +1| +1|     |   | +1|    |   |+1| (Junts yet to declare EP affiliation)
|PL     |   |   |   |     |   | +1|    |   |  |
|RO     |   | +1|   |     |   |   |    |   |  |
|NL     |   |   | +1|     |   | +1|    | +1|  |
|SE     |   | +1|   |     |   |   |    |   |  | (My calculations)
|AT     |   |   |   |   +1|   |   |    |   |  | (My calculations)
|DK     |   |   | +1|     |   |   |    |   |  |
|FI     |   |   |   |   +1|   |   |    |   |  |
|SK     | +1|   |   |     |   |   |    |   |  |
|IE     | +1|   | +1|     |   |   |    |   |  |
|HR     |   | +1|   |     |   |   |    |   |  |
|EE     | +1|   |   |     |   |   |    |   |  |
+-------+---+---+---+-----+---+---+----+---+--+
|Change | +5| -5|-11|   -8| -1|  0| -29| +3| 0|
+-------+---+---+---+-----+---+---+----+---+--+
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not assume that it demanded a long calculation.

Comment: It wasn't as much a long calculation as waiting for results to become official (and even then, we're not 100% there yet).

Comment: Dutch seats will go to VVD, FVD, and PVV. Source(dutch: https://www.nu.nl/europese-verkiezingen-2019/5910381/extra-zetel-na-brexit-gaat-niet-naar-groenlinks-maar-naar-forum.html)

Comment: @Aldwoni Thank you, I've updated my answer accordingly.